# IOS: Clear Previous content in Modal viewcontroller

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uitableview, modalviewcontroller

In my application, I have used one modal viewcontroller which contains one TableView with multiple textfields.

Say My main viewcontroller called SridharViewController and the modal viewcontroller called ResultsViewController

There is one button in SridharViewController , touching that button will open the modal(ResultsViewController)

```
[self presentModalViewController:resultsViewController animated:YES];
```

And in the results view controller , There are many text fields which are aligned in the TableView. and one 'OK' button . pressing 'OK' button will dismiss the modal

```
[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSLog(@"cellForRowAtIndexPath called");
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }

    //UITextField *formTextField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(30, 11, 270, 30)];
    UITextField *formTextField =nil;
    if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) {
        if(indexPath.row == 0){
            formTextField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(30, 12, 270, 30)];
        }
        else{
            formTextField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(30, 11, 270, 30)];
        }

    }else{
        if(indexPath.row == 0){
            formTextField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50, 12, 670, 30)];
        }
        else{
            formTextField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50, 11, 670, 30)];
        }

    }


    formTextField.placeholder = [self.formFields objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    formTextField.tag = indexPath.row;
    formTextField.text=@"";
    formTextField.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;
    formTextField.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    formTextField.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleNone;
    formTextField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeNumbersAndPunctuation;
    [formTextField setAutocapitalizationType:UITextAutocapitalizationTypeNone];
    [formTextField setAutocorrectionType:UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo];
    formTextField.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    formTextField.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentLeft;
    formTextField.delegate = self;
    [formTextField setEnabled: YES];
    [formTextField setReturnKeyType:UIReturnKeyNext];
    [self.textFields addObject:formTextField];
    [cell addSubview:formTextField];
    return cell;
}
```

When I calling the modal view second time , the modal shows the previous content. I want to clear that previous content.
I have tried both updates and reload functions. None of them calling the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method.

```
[self.theTable reloadInputViews];
```

Please provide me the best way to do this.

Comment: What you mean by previous content? what type of content? Does TextField hold their text data?

Comment: Call reloadData on tableview, then cellForRowAtIndexPath will get called.

Comment: "When i calling the modal view second time" -- How are you doing this? You need to provide more code for us to help you.

Comment: Can you please show where and how you are providing data to textfeilds in tableview?Because when you present modal view second it actually create new instance of tableview if you have not saved instance of modal controller.

Comment: Please post the whole method where you present the view controller. Unless you're saving a reference to resultsViewController, whenever you present it, it should be a new instance, which shouldn't show the previous contents.

Comment: You `There are many text fields which are aligned in the TableView` so your textfield hold on to data which you have previously added? what is the content not sure? Its text in textfield or textfield it self? what content you want to reload.

Comment: @Dilip, Text in textfields

Comment: is there any way to call view didload method ?

Comment: You shouldn't call viewDidLoad yourself. If you present a new instance, its viewDidLoad will be called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem by this code

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        NSLog(@" cellForRowAtIndexPath create new cell %d",indexPath.row);
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }
     NSLog(@" cellForRowAtIndexPath update  cell %d",indexPath.row);
    //UITextField *formTextField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(30, 11, 270, 30)];
    for(UITextField *lbl in [cell subviews])
    {
          NSLog(@" removing UITextField from  cell %d",indexPath.row);
        if(lbl.tag == (indexPath.row+2)){
             [lbl removeFromSuperview];

        }



    }
    if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) {
        if(indexPath.row == 0){
            self.tableTextField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(30, 12, 270, 30)];
        }
        else{
            self.tableTextField  = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(30, 11, 270, 30)];
        }

    }else{
        if(indexPath.row == 0){
            self.tableTextField  = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50, 12, 670, 30)];
        }
        else{
            self.tableTextField  = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50, 11, 670, 30)];
        }

    }


    self.tableTextField .placeholder = [self.formFields objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    self.tableTextField .tag = indexPath.row+2;
    self.tableTextField .adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;
    self.tableTextField .textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    self.tableTextField .borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleNone;
    self.tableTextField .keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeNumbersAndPunctuation;
    [self.tableTextField  setAutocapitalizationType:UITextAutocapitalizationTypeNone];
    [self.tableTextField  setAutocorrectionType:UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo];
    self.tableTextField .backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    self.tableTextField .textAlignment = UITextAlignmentLeft;
    self.tableTextField .delegate = self;
    self.tableTextField .text=@"";
    [self.tableTextField  setEnabled: YES];
    [self.tableTextField  setReturnKeyType:UIReturnKeyNext];
    [cell addSubview:self.tableTextField ];
    return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In `viewWillAppear` do the following

```
arrayOfInputs = [NSArray array];
[self.tableview reloadData];
```

where `arrayOfInputs` is where you store your objects that would display on tableview. After making the data source empty and reload table view, all the contents will clear. Then you can reload the table view with required data.

Answer (score 0):

When you want to reload tableview please use below line

```
[self.tableview reloadData]
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this code in ViewDidLoad method this will clear all textfield text

```
for (UIView *view in [self.view subviews]) {
        if ([view isKindOfClass:[UITextField class]]) {
            UITextField *textField = (UITextField *)view;

            textField.text = @"";
        }
    }
```